# Генерация случайного цвета по двум координатам

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

возникла необходимость в генерации случайного цвета для 2D вершины по ее координатам. Первое, что пришло в голову, так это вот это:

```
function generateColorByPosition(xPos, yPos) {
    const x = xPos.toString()[0];
    const y = yPos.toString()[0];
    return `#${x}${y}${x}${y}${x}${y}`;
}
```

Генерируется все прекрасно, но если вершины находятся рядом, то цвета становятся
очень похожими. Допустим, если взять две вершины (0; 0) и (4; 4), то их цвета будут следующими #000000 и #444444. Может существует какой-нибудь алгоритм для этой цели, чтобы отличались вершины как в далеке друг от друга, так и в близи. Генерацию случайного цвета не предлагать, нужна именно генерация по позиции вершины.

Comment: Понятие "вершины" про цвет - не слышал. Переформулируйте, или если сложно описать - нарисуйте что вы хотите. Переход от одного цвета к другому, контраст, или какой-то другой извесный эффект. Возможно... почитайте про HSV - в модели HSV проще найти оттенки нужного цвета (преобразования правда сложноваты).

Comment: вы хотите что бы два соседних пикселя всегда отличались?

Comment: Можете создать массив нужных цветов, и выбирать их по "остатку от деления" т.е. `color = color_table[xPos % sizeof(color_table)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял вам нужна функция которая бы всегда возвращала одинаковый ответ для одной и той же точки, но отличался, для соседних. 

Тогда вам нужна `хеш-функция`. 

У вас тоже хеш-функция, но можно написать функцию с большим разбросом значений. Вот пример моей:

```js
function generateColorByPosition(xPos, yPos) {
  const x = ((xPos + 17) * 23).toString(16).padStart(3, 0);
  const y = ((yPos + 13) * 31).toString(16).padStart(3, 0);
  return `#${x}${y}`.slice(0, 7);
}
for (let x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
  for (let y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = generateColorByPosition(x, y);
    div.style.backgroundColor = div.innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Иногда случается баг, и появляется куча черных цветов из-за того, что в цвете появляется точка. Например: #1ba.c2

Comment: @QuickDzen какие вы числа вы передаете в функцию?

Comment: от 0 до 18 по x и от 0 до 14 по y

Comment: @QuickDzen я изменил код с вашим диапазоном и черного цвета не вижу, как и точки в цвете.